# Disable Flask warnings about view functions not returning a response?

Tags: python, flask

I am developing an API using Flask, a service not meant to be rendering any templates but simply returning json in the form of `{"message": "message here", "status_code": 200, "data": {}}"`.

I have several routes and each modifies a global response object attached to `Flask.g`:

```
from flask import g

from project import app


@app.route('/users/', methods=["GET"])
def get_users():
    ...
    g.res.data["message"] = "Successfully queried users as specified."
    # default g.res.status_code == 200

@app.route('/users/', methods=["POST"])
def post_users():
    ...
    g.res.data["message"] = "Successfully created User."
    g.res.status_code = 201
```

Then, returning the response data to the user is handled by an `app.after_request`:

```
from flask import g, jsonify

from project import app


@app.after_request
def after_request(response: None):
    return jsonify(g.res)
```

However, Flask still (correctly) believes that the view function is not returning a response, since *technically* the view function is not, but the after_request handler is.

Is there any inherit problems in my approach to handling the response data? I purposely switched to using `app.after_request` to avoid duplicating `return jsonify(g.res)` at the end of each view function.

If there are no problems with this way, how should I go about disabling these warnings?

Edit: The error is being raised in `Flask.app.make_response` where a `ValueError` is raised on the response being `None` and other conversions are attempted later (from a `str` to a `Flask.Response` object, for example).

I will likely just modify this file directly to handle my specific use-case until I find an idiomatic way to approach this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subclass the `Flask` class and override the `make_response` method. Move the logic from your handler into the method. If there was no response returned by the view but there is valid data in `g.res`, then build the response and return it, otherwise defer to the default behavior.

```
class GResFlask(Flask):
    def make_response(self, rv):
        if not rv and g.res.data:
            return jsonify(g.res)
        return super().make_response(rv)

app = GResFlask(__name__)
```

It's important to note that `after_request` handlers may be added by extensions, and the interface provided by Flask means that they will be expecting a valid response object. So you always want to return a valid response from `make_response`.